# Vue data not getting overwritten by a eventHub call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I cant figure out, why my variable inside `data()` isnt getting overwritten.

Code looks like this:

```
export default {
  props: ["store", "link", "index", "isStoreOpen"],
  data() {
    return {
      hovered_over_icon: false,
      window_width: window.innerWidth,
      opened: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleRestaurantView() {
      this.link()
    },
    check_for_breaks(text){
      return text.replace(/\*break\*/g, '<br/>');
    },
    change_state(state){
      this.opened = state
    }
  },
  computed: {
    url() {
      return ((this.store) ? `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/${this.store.address.location.lat},${this.store.address.location.lon}` : '#')
    },
    isOpen() {
      return this.store.openNow;
    }
  },
  created(){
    eventHub.$on('restaurantOpened', (state) => this.change_state(state));
    eventHub.$on('changeFilteredRestaurantsAfterRestaurantVisit', (state) => this.store = state);
  }
}
</script>
```

But when I log the `this.opened` after reassigning new value, I get the correct one, however when I check Vue console, it stayed on `null`.

Even if I do `this.$forceUpdate()` it doesnt get updated.

Never happened this to me in my Vue career so far, a bit confused.

Comment: Problems with event busses are usually timing-related: Something isn't receiving an event because the event was sent sent before the listening component is ready. One of the many reasons I try to **never** use event busses.

Your description is lacking details to tell what's going on. Where do you do the console.log? When is that event bus triggered? Does that event trigger other behaviour as well? Maybe in the parent component? Maybe the parent is recrewating the child component, essentially resetting the sate?

Following dataflow in event busses is hard...

Comment: @Jousi Also you're leaking memory by not deregistering the event listeners from the event hub when the component is destroyed.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yeah I havent finished building the component yet, but its true that it might affect it as well.
@LinusBorg Well, as I said, I log it right after the value of it gets reassigned `But when I log the this.opened after reassigning new value`. That means in the `change_state()` function.

Comment: I just dont understand, why Vue doesnt re-render it, after `change_state()` changes its data :/ even when I tried firing `this.$forceUpdate()` inside it.